# How to implement the two-finger swipe gesture in Cocoa to go back and forward?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, navigation, magic-mouse, swipe-gesture

Several applications like Safari and the Finder go back and forward when you [swipe with two fingers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7r2m.png) on your Magic Mouse (or with three fingers on your Magic Trackpad).

How would I implement this in my Cocoa application? What classes are available?

Comment: I did a quick search in the XCode developer documentation for "multitouch", and there's a whole section in the Mac OS X SnowLeopard (no space) Release Notes discussing multitouch. There's way too much to post here, but I suggest you read those notes as a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three finger swipes are easiest, because NSResponder already does the work for you:

```
- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
```

If you want to support two finger swipes (which I don't think technically can be classified as swipes, but rather scroll gestures), you'll have to manually process the touches- see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW10

Comment: This works with a two-finger swipe on the Magic Mouse. I guess you were talking about the Magic Trackpad? I don't have one yet, so I asked about the Magic Mouse. I need one to test, though.

Comment: You're right- I have a Magic Trackpad but no Magic Mouse, and on the Magic Trackpad two-finger swipes scroll.

Comment: For two finger swipes on a trackpad, check out https://github.com/Kapeli/SwipableWebView.

Comment: Just converted this simple obj-c solution to swift and it works great: https://github.com/oscardelben/CocoaNavigationGestures  (the swift solution is apart of a bigger opensource project, but it took like 10 min to do it)

Answer (score 5):

For me two-finger swipe worked with the Trackpad by subclassing the NSView descendant holding the info to be swiped (e.g. a NSScrollView instance) and then to implement -(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event. This method will be invoked for two-finger swipes, the direction of the swipe can be taken from the [event deltaX] and [event deltaY] properties.