# Custom Swipe Gestures

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it somehow possible to add a 3-finger swipe gesture on a system scale, like a hotkey ?
Yes, just like the notification center gesture, only from the other side. (sandboxed)

Maybe by using a Desktop-size overlay window that is transparent and captures swipe gestures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use a transparent, desktop-sized overlay window, [CocoaNavigationGestures](https://github.com/oscardelben/CocoaNavigationGestures) on Github may be of use for code on getting left and right swipes on both Leopard and Lion.

Comment: THX. Now if the overlay would have ignoremouseclicks set to true but [self setAcceptTouchEvents:YES];, would you think it could work then ?
Also, there seems to be already a 3-finger swipe build-in into cocoa to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747603/how-to-implement-the-two-finger-swipe-gesture-in-cocoa-to-go-back-and-forward/6748111#6748111.
Would you rather recommend to use this or CocoaNavigationGestures ?

Comment: I'd give the CocoaNavigationGestures sample code a go. It believe it works with both two and three finger swipes, depending on user settings in System Preferences and is compatible with both Leopard and Lion/ML. I believe if you have `setAcceptTouchEvents:YES` it should be fine.

Comment: As you may know the Notification Center has a special gesture: 2 finger swipe from the right edge of the trackpad. I don't see how such a truly custom swipe gesture (from the edge) is possible with CocoaNavigationGestures, or what do you think?

Comment: I've tried it and can do a gesture just like Notification Center's, but from the other side, just fine.

Comment: Wow, and it only toggles when swiped from the edge? (sorry, can't try it out myself at the moment)

Comment: It doesn't toggle when *only* swiped from the edge, but it could surely be made to.

Comment: Mh .. unfortunately the gesture only works when the overlay window is key and when the overlay is key it "swallows" all gestures and won't let other gestures (like 2 finger right or left) which might be needed by other apps pass through.

Answer (score 2):

Create a gesture recognizer and use `setNumberOfTouchesRequired = 3`

Comment: ok, how do I add a gesture recognizer ? Also would it be a system level gesture & sandboxed ? Thx