# Catch two finger double click in SwiftUI & VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, voiceover

Does anybody know how to catch or disable/replace the two-finger double-click in an SwiftUI view when Voice Over is running?

The solution proposed here [SwiftUI: Two-finger swipe ( scroll ) gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137652/swiftui-two-finger-swipe-scroll-gesture) works, but not when voice over is ON. VO seems to catch the event early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself. This gesture is called "Magic Tap" and you can intercept it in SwiftUI like this:

```
.accessibilityAction(.magicTap, {
  // process 2-finger double click
})
```